# If I visit the Temple Of Sinawava at Zion National Park, how close can we get with our car?

Tags: usa, national-parks, utah

I’ve just been told by “someone” that when we visit Zion National Park we *must* take a bus up to the Temple of Sinawava. Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During the main season at the park (spring to fall, essentially), private vehicles are banned on the main park roads.  There would simply be too many of them.

You can park in various parking areas near the park gates, and there is a free bus that will transport you around the park.  It's quite convenient and runs fairly frequently.  I thought it would be really inconvenient, but it isn't.

If you absolutely must drive your own vehicle on the roads, you can usually do so in the winter.  Check the park's website for details on when private vehicles are allowed.

Comment: It's not strictly true that private vehicles are not allowed on park roads during the summer. Route 9, which cuts through the park, is accessible and does require driving past the park gates. Those who stay at Zion Lodge are also able to drive as far as the lodge. Neither of these points helps the OP however, who will, as you correctly mentioned, need to take the bus to reach the Temple of Sinawava.

Comment: @cbw Quite right.  My answer is slightly oversimple but I was trying to answer the original poster's question specifically.

Comment: Absolutely. I just wanted to add some clarification in case anyone finds this question and answer in the future.

Comment: Now that I've been there, I can see why they must minimize vehicle traffic in the area.